# Podio update app field API not listening for hidden_create_view_edit

Tags: api, parameters, podio

looking at https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/update-an-app-field-22356

as the documentation states we cannot pass the new `hidden_create_view_edit` attribute to the API call. (FYI: I attempted to pass it anyway but the documentation is right, it does not take the `hidden_create_view_edit` into account).

Can you please listen for this parameter? And in what timeframe would this become available? I need this to clone a ton of app fields with right settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. It seems that we haven't included support for this specific method while implementing great new attribute `hidden_create_view_edit`. This is now fixed and planned for public release some time during next week.

Comment: Hi Pavlo, thanks for the quick response! How will we know when the next release is in production?

Comment: It should be released now :) Give it a try!